# failed to test azure purview SDK for Java due to "IntelliJ Authentication not available

Tags: java, azure, azure-java-sdk

I'm following this [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/purview/azure-analytics-purview-catalog/src/samples/java/com/azure/analytics/purview/catalog/ListGlossaries.java) to test purview SDK for java, it could be built successful, but when I run this java file ,it's failed due to "IntelliJ Authentication". BTW, I just edit one java file and run it in cmd windows, also I logon the IntelliJ with azure account. any suggestions appreciated

error messages:

10:30:44.138 [main] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.IntelliJCacheAccessor - IntelliJ Authentication not available. Please log in with Azure Tools for IntelliJ plugin in the IDE.